# Sum multiple rows using dplyr by variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to tidy up my database. I have multiple sites, subsites, and categories as well as other columns. What i want is to combine my database together to produce a list of each subsite's category and total % cover for each category type. Below is what my database sort of looks like (obviously with far less variables and data)

```
BenSam <-
Site|Subsite|Category|%Cover
----|-------|--------|------
Sam |Sam1   |Coral   |19
Sam |Sam1   |Coral   |2
Sam |Sam1   |Misc    |14
PK  |PK1    |Coral   |12
PK  |PK2    |Coral   |13
PK  |PK2    |Misc    |8
PK  |PK2    |Misc    |13
```

What i am trying to do is end up with a database that looks like:

```
BenSam <-
Site|Subsite|Category|%Cover
----|-------|--------|------
Sam |Sam1   |Coral   |21
Sam |Sam1   |Misc    |14
PK  |PK1    |Coral   |12
PK  |PK2    |Coral   |13
PK  |PK2    |Misc    |21
```

I have searched quite a lot, and i found this piece of code using dplyr that seemed quite hopefull. And whilst it does what i need, the output in my "Cover" column was incorrect.

```
BenSamPercent <- BenSam %>%
   group_by(Site, Subsite, Category) %>%
   summarise(Cover = sum(X..Cover))
```

Any help will be immensely appreciated thank you

Comment: This looks like it should work.  What output do you get?

Comment: Make sure you are using the right column name in `sum`. Is your column name `X..Cover` ?

Comment: Change your `%Cover` column to some other non funky name and then try your formula again...other than this it looks correct.

Comment: Remove the two periods for one and code should work. `%Cover` becomes `X.Cover` in data.frame build as names cannot begin with special chars or numbers.

Comment: Hey there. So it turns out there was an issue when setting my % Cover factor as.numeric (it was registered as factor instead), and this was the issue that was causing my values to change. I solved this by simply coping and pasting my database in excel and pasting as "values only". This seemed to solve the problem however im unsure what caused the issue in the first place. Thanks for your help though :)